# nslookup returns Unknown default server

Tags: networking, dns

I have an isolated network with two Windows Machines. The IP addresses of the machines are `10.11.0.100` and `10.20.0.200`. They are connected directly to each other (i.e in the same broadcast domain via a switch). There are no other machines in the network. I am able to ping between these two machines.

However if I do `nslookup 10.20.0.200` from `10.11.0.100` I get unknown server error:

```
Default Server:  UnKnown
Address:  ::1
```

Why is this happening. I am investigating time sync issue between the two servers and thought this might be a probable cause.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running two machines in an isolated network and do not mention setting up a DNS server on either of them, most likely you have not set up the DNS server in your isolated network.

You have not configured the DNS client either (because the server doesn't exist so there is no way to configure it properly).

`nslookup` does not work and returns "unknown server" because it cannot find a DNS server which has not been configured and does not exist.

---

Unless your syncing solution requires name resolution it's not a likely cause of problems.